# Aaggrid causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have some strange error when using `aggrid` in Angular 10. I created a simple example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mnbupy?file=src/app/app.component.html):

When I have this setup I get this error:

`Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '100'.`

```html
Number of Rows {{getNumberOfRows()}}

<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
```

however, when I change it to this:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>

Number of Rows {{getNumberOfRows()}}
```

The error is gone. How can this be and how can I fix it?!

Comment: You have continuously calling the **getNumberOfRows()** function.Each time the count will vary so that they throw an error. @matthaias

Comment: and why is the error gone if i put it below <ag-grid-angular ?

Comment: You were rendering the count value after executing the table data values. @matthias

Comment: sorry, this does not makes sense to me since i use a timer to provide data after 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you here: https://angular-ivy-qroisr.stackblitz.io

Basically you need to be setting your rowData only after the grid is ready
But for you to utilize the generateEvents function you would have to pass in a context to the gridOptions

Typically in my projects I create a subscription to the ngrx data within the onGridReady function and then do the same

Comment: Downvoted unfortunately. Link does not open, hence no code provided.